# Grouping by Multi-Indices of both Row and Column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have created a table using Pandas following material from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html).

The table created makes use of Multi-Indices for both columns and rows.
[image]

I am trying to compute the descriptive statistics for each year and subject, meaning, displaying for instance the mean of 2013 for Bob, the mean for 2013 for Guido, and the mean for 2013 for Sue, for all subjects, and for all years. The means for Bob would consider the means for HR and Temp.
Note: The types are the same as a coincidence, as this is not the case for the table implemented. Other subjects not included in the screenshot have varying types.

The closest I have managed to come to the solution is through the following code
`df.groupby(level = 0, axis = 0).describe()` 
This grouped the data by the year, however, did not group by subject also.

Comment: Please never post dataframes as images, always as code that can be run to create a dataframe, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: The code is in the link I included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing links to external websites is also discouraged as they may change/disappear at any time without SO control

Having said that, the link provides most of the tools you need to answer your questions. More specifically, a combination of `stack` and `mean` should give you what you specifically asked about:

```
health_data.stack().mean(level = 'year')
```

produces

```
subject Bob     Guido   Sue
year            
2013    28.4    40.400  34.15
2014    43.2    38.025  41.10
```

or more generally

```
health_data.stack().groupby('year').describe()
```

produces a long dataframe with the statistics grouped by year, for each subject:

```
subject Bob                                     Guido                       Sue
count   mean    std min 25% 50% 75% max count   mean    ... 75% max count   mean    std min 25% 50% 75% max
year                                                                                    
2013    4.0 28.4    11.580443   13.0    22.75   31.3    36.95   38.0    4.0 40.400  ... 42.500  50.0    4.0 34.15   4.297674    30.0    30.75   33.95   37.35   38.7
2014    4.0 43.2    7.566593    36.4    37.15   42.2    48.25   52.0    4.0 38.025  ... 39.875  44.0    4.0 41.10   12.961996   28.0    35.65   38.70   44.15   59.0
```